# Order by average date (timestamp)

Tags: mysql, average

I'd appreciate your help with this one.

I have an app where a user creates a team of 4 friends. The app inserts the friends into the database, this table has a 'question' column and 'answer' column, the last one is updated when a friend answers the question. This 'friend' table also has a 'date_answer' (Timestamp) column, with default value set to ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

All is working fine, what I have to do now is to order the teams by the average date_answer of the team. I mean, the first team will be the one where the users answered the questions first.

I hope I explained myself ok. The tables are as follows:

```
Teams
------
id
name
created
*******

Friends
-------
id
name
team_id
question
answer
date_answer
```

May be a case where Team 1 answered like this:
Friend 1: 1am
Friend 2: 2am
Friend 3: 3am
Friend 4: 3pm

And team 2:
Friend 1: 1am
Friend 2: 4am
Friend 3: 1am
Friend 4: 6pm

The winner would be Team 1, because friends answered faster.

Comment: Please show the calculation that determined that team 1 won.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it something like this should help out. Ive included a third team in which one member of the team is still struggling to answer the question....

```
create table Teams
(
id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
name varchar(50) not null,
created datetime not null
);

create table Friends
(
id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
name varchar(50) not null,
team_id int unsigned not null,
question varchar(100) default null,
answer varchar(100) default null,
date_answer timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

insert into Teams (name,created) values ("Team 1",now());
insert into Teams (name,created) values ("Team 2",now());
insert into Teams (name,created) values ("Team 3",now());


insert into Friends (name,team_id,question,answer,date_answer) values ("Bob",1,"What Is Your Name?","Bob",'2012-08-15 01:00:00');
insert into Friends (name,team_id,question,answer,date_answer) values ("Joe",1,"What Is Your Name?","Joe",'2012-08-15 02:00:00');
insert into Friends (name,team_id,question,answer,date_answer) values ("Tim",1,"What Is Your Name?","Tim",'2012-08-15 03:00:00');
insert into Friends (name,team_id,question,answer,date_answer) values ("Tom",1,"What Is Your Name?","Tom",'2012-08-15 15:00:00');

insert into Friends (name,team_id,question,answer,date_answer) values ("Jon",2,"What Is Your Name?","Jon",'2012-08-15 01:00:00');
insert into Friends (name,team_id,question,answer,date_answer) values ("Jim",2,"What Is Your Name?","Jim",'2012-08-15 04:00:00');
insert into Friends (name,team_id,question,answer,date_answer) values ("Josh",2,"What Is Your Name?","Josh",'2012-08-15 01:00:00');
insert into Friends (name,team_id,question,answer,date_answer) values ("Jack",2,"What Is Your Name?","Jack",'2012-08-15 18:00:00');

insert into Friends (name,team_id,question,answer,date_answer) values ("Dave",3,"What Is Your Name?","Jon",'2012-08-15 01:00:00');
insert into Friends (name,team_id,question,answer,date_answer) values ("Dug",3,"What Is Your Name?","Jim",'2012-08-15 04:00:00');
insert into Friends (name,team_id,question,answer,date_answer) values ("Dappy",3,"What Is Your Name?",null,null);

-- Winning team must have an answer from all teams members and have earliest average 
-- date_answer
select t.name as "Winning Team",
sum(case when f.answer is not null then 1 else 0 end) as answerCount,
count(*) as teamCount,
timestamp(avg(f.date_answer)) as averageAnswerDate
from Teams t
left join Friends f on f.team_id = t.id
group by t.name
having answerCount = teamCount
order by averageAnswerDate asc
limit 1;
```